# Why does declaring Delegate<T> inside Class<T> generates a VS warning?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, delegates

There are lots of discussions around whether to strongly type event arguments. This question is not about that. I have the following class (only relevant code included):

```
public abstract class Thread<TSender, TEventArgs>:
    System.IDisposable
    where TSender: Thread<TSender, TEventArgs>, new()
    where TEventArgs: System.EventArgs, new()
{
    public delegate void ThreadEventHandler (Thread<TSender, TEventArgs> sender, ThreadEventArgs e);

    // This declaratino generates a VS 2012 warning.
    public delegate void ThreadProcessIterationEventHandler<TSender, TEventArgs> (TSender sender, TEventArgs e);
}
```

The declaration of the second delegate generates VS2012 warnings:

```
1. Type parameter 'TSender' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'Thread<TSender,TEventArgs>'

2. Type parameter 'TEventArgs' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'Thread<TSender,TEventArgs>'
```

This structure seems logically correct since the intention is to provide wrapped threading mechanism for derived classes. It is certainly legal code and compiles and runs as expected.

I would have thought that having a self-pointing-constraint could be considered bad practice but why are `TSender` and `TEventArgs` flagged as warnings? Is that not the same as declaring `NestedClass<TSender, TEventArgs>`?

Should I be looking out for something?

**UPDATE**: The purpose of the second delegate is to allow child classes to fire strongly-typed events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the second declaration which is failing:

```
ThreadProcessIterationEventHandler<TSender, TEventArgs>(...)
```

You can't declare a *new* type parameter called `TSender` within a type which already declares a type parameter `TSender`.

You don't *want* a new generic type though - you just want to reuse the enclosing type's type parameters:

```
public delegate void ThreadProcessIterationEventHandler(TSender sender, TEventArgs e);
```

Comment: Thanks. Have updated the question with more info. If I use your declaration, that would mean subscribers would need to cast the TSender and TEventArgs wouldn't it? Derived classes would need to declare their own typed delegates. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: @RaheelKhan: No, they wouldn't. You could use `Thread<Control, EventArgs>.ThreadProcessIterationHandler`. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, mind you...

Comment: Ok so this base class is part of a library. The intention was to pack everything in this class so derived classes would not need to do anything additional to fire strongly-typed events of type `U` where `U: Thread<U, UEventArgs>`. Not sure why (to me) this seems difficult to explain. Trying to understand your last comment to see how that could work.

Comment: @RaheelKhan: There's nothing extra you'd need to do. Personally I'd declare the delegates as top level types though, instead of nesting them. Then you *would* need to make them generic again, but you could always declared events using the type arguments within `Thread<,>`. I would also advise using a different name - developers who see `Thread` are likely to think of `System.Threading.Thread`...

Comment: Thank you. I believe I did declare the delegate as top-level before and then decided to nest it but without removing the type parameters. Thus the confusion. Good point to change the name as well.

Comment: @RaheelKhan: Right. So are you all set now? (I really would still make them top-level delegates...)

Comment: Yes all set! Any good pointers to read up on why delegates should be top-level?

Comment: @RaheelKhan: Just that in general it makes life easier for *all* types to be top level, unless you have a really good reason for them *not* to be. It's a guideline more than anything else.

Answer (score 9):

You're declaring a delegate, with *new type specifiers*.  You can declare this without the extra generic types:

```
public delegate void ThreadProcessIterationEventHandler(TSender sender, TEventArgs e);
```

By putting the `<TSender,TEventArgs>` in the delegate declaration, it's defining *new types* for use in the delegate, with the same name as the containing generic type.  It's like you were writing:

```
public delegate void ThreadProcessIterationEventHandler<TFoo, TBar>(TFoo sender, TBar e);
```

Basically, by adding those types in, you actually make the delegate work with types different than the containing class.  Since you used the same names, the compiler assumes this is a mistake, and warns you.

Comment: Thanks. How else could I provide derived classes with a delegate specialized to their type? Basically, I did not want the derived classes to have to do anything except implement two abstract functions.

Comment: @RaheelKhan Just as I wrote in my first example.  The delegate will already use `TSender` and `TEventArgs` from the containing class definition - you don't need to redefine those.

Comment: Hmmm... Let me revisit why I felt the need to this in the first place and revert back. By the way, just to help me understand, since my code compiles and runs as expected, are there any gotchas besides the warning and unnecessary typing of the delegate?

Comment: @RaheelKhan If you leave the unnecessary typing in place, the user must specify the types, and they don't have to match the class types - it basically "takes away" the safety you're going for here...